# Accessing Route URL Parameter in Middleware in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-5.3, laravel-middleware

I am having a hard time accessing the Route URL Parameter in Middleware after updating from `Laravel 5.1` to `Laravel 5.3`.

**Here is my route file:**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['app.access']], function()
{
    Route::resource('apps/{apps}/houses', 'HouseController',
                    ['except' => ['index', 'create', 'edit']]);

    Route::get('apps/{apps}/houses/colour/{colour}', 'HouseController@colourCheck');
    ...
}
```

**Kernel.php** has RouteMiddleware updated like this:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        // Added ones....
        'jwt.auth' => \Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken::class,
        'jwt.refresh' => \Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\RefreshToken::class,
        // Custom Middleware
        'app.access' => \App\Http\Middleware\AppAccess::class,
    ];
```

In **Laravel 5.1** and I was able to access route parameter from middleware like this and I had no trouble:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
        $appId = $request->route('apps');
        ...
}
```

But, since upgrading to **Laravel 5.3**, the above code started returned `$appId` as `null`. I also tried accessing route parameter like `$appId = $request->apps` and this was not working as well.

So I then changed the Middleware to get the url parameter like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
        $appId = $request->route()->parameters('apps');
        ...
}
```

Since changing to the above, the middleware seems to be working for the first route. But then, I am having problem when going to the second route that has 2 parameters. For some reason, the above code fails and when returning `$request->route()->parameters('apps')` from middleware, I am getting an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [apps] => 1
    [colour] => green
)
```

Why is that? Why is it not returning just the `$appId` which is `1`? Am I missing something or is it a bug in Laravel 5.3? I want the Middleware to access only the `appId` parameter from the url and nothing else from the route. Can someone help me here please?

**Update 1:**

I tried changing the Middleware to get parameter like this:

```
$parameters = $request->route()->parameters();
$appId = $parameters['apps'];
```

In the above, I am getting the error:

```
Undefined index: apps
```

But when I `print_r($parameters);`, the output is like this:

```
Array
(
    [apps] => 1
    [day] => tuesday
)
[]
```

**Solution:**

In the end, I found out the reason for this odd behaviour was due the parameter name in the url.

The following resources routes were generating route url parameter as `app` instead of `apps`. I dont know why though:

```
Route::resource('apps/{apps}/houses', 'HouseController',
                        ['except' => ['index', 'create', 'edit']]);
```

Whereas the following routes were generating route url parameter as `apps`:

```
Route::get('apps/{apps}/houses/colour/{colour}', 'HouseController@colourCheck');
```

Due to this odd behaviour, some routes were returning `null` for the parameter name `apps` and some where showing the parameter. Once I renamed all route parameters to `{app}` in the `routes/api.php` and Middleware, the Middleware started working the way it should.

I don't know why the resource routes were creating the parameter as `app`, but the above fixed the error for me, atleast for now.

Comment: The route() method should work in the middleware Laravel 5.3 to get a route param. Works fine for me.

Comment: @schellingerht For me the `route()` method is always returning as null in Laravel 5.3. I have already added the middleware to `RouteMiddleware` in `Kernel.php` and its still null. I understand that Laravel 5.3 has changed the route file to api and web and the middleware I am using is for the api group, does that change anything? I dont understand why `route()` in middleware is showing null after updating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways for accessing parameters in a middleware:

**Method 1**
`$request->route('parameter_name');`
Here `parameter_name` refers to what we called the parameter in the route.

**Method 2**
`$request->route()->parameters();`
This method will return an array of all the parameters.

Comment: When I tried the Method 1, I am getting it as null. In method 2, I only want to get the `appId` so when I add it as `$request->route()->parameters('apps')`, I am still getting the array of all parameters when the url has multiple parameter like the example in my OP.

Comment: For Method 1 - Make sure you are using the same name for `parameter_name` for what you called it in route.php. As for `Route::get('apps/{apps}/houses/colour/{colour}', 'HouseController@colourCheck');` you will call it as `$request->route('apps')` or `$request->route('colour')`. And `$request->route()->parameters();` doesn't accecpt any parameters, it always returns an array.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @AmitGupta I did use the `route()` method as `$request->route('apps')`, but it is returning as `null`. `apps` is the parameter name called in `routes/api.php`.  I have also added the middleware to `RouteMiddleware` in `Kernel.php` but still its returned as null.

Comment: I tried the second method to get the `appId` parameter from the array but that is not working neither. I have updated my post with what I tried and what output I am getting when I use `print_r`.

Comment: Have updating my post with the solution that worked for now. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

[**Resource Parameters Are Singular By Default**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0)

If you would like to maintain the previous behavior instead of automatically singularizing resource route parameters, you may make the following call to the singularResourceParameters method in your  AppServiceProvider:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::singularResourceParameters(false);
```

Comment: ah... thanks @HarryBosh for the link. Now it makes sense on why the route parameter is singularised in 5.3 only.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was the solution for Laravel 6.

In the routes file add `->middleware()` like this:

```
Route::resource('orders', 'OrdersController')->middleware('roles:Admin,System');
```

Now to retrieve the parameters in the middleware class:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$roles)
{
     // now $roles contains: ['Admin, 'System']
}
```